# Draw isometric lines of Poincare's disk

Tags: tikz-pgf

Trying to draw the "equal distance" lines of poincare's disk, like in this post : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1343730/390217

I tried using hyperbolic functions, but that's not it, the result is not quite right :
[image: wrong poincare disk]

Here's the code, you can get some nice pictures playing around with the values and functions.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefPoint(1,0){A}
  \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
  \draw (A) -- (-1,0);
  \draw (0,1) -- (0,-1);
\foreach \nt in {0.1,0.2,...,1}{
\pgfmathsetmacro\nx{cosh(\nt)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\ny{sinh(\nt)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\mx{(-\nx)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\my{(-\ny)}
  \tkzClipCircle(O,A)
  \tkzDefPoint(\nx,\ny){z1}
  \tkzDefPoint(\nx,\my){z2}
  \tkzDefPoint(\mx,\my){z3}
  \tkzDefPoint(\mx,\ny){z4}
  \tkzDefPoint(\ny,\nx){z5}
  \tkzDefPoint(\my,\nx){z6}
  \tkzDefPoint(\my,\mx){z7}
  \tkzDefPoint(\ny,\mx){z8}
  \tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=z1 and z2](O,A)
  \tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=z3 and z4](O,A)
  \tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=z1 and z4](O,A)
  \tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=z2 and z3](O,A)
  \tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=z5 and z6](O,A)
  \tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=z7 and z8](O,A)
  \tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=z5 and z8](O,A)
  \tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=z6 and z7](O,A)
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Anyone know if I can get to the right result by tweaking the functions or values ?
I wouldn't know how to get it by projecting the timelike lines of a paraboloïd like it's explained in the above mentioned post...

Thanks for any help/suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved !

I contacted the author of the mentionned picture and he graciously sent me the code used. It was a very long list of coordinate points computer generated, so I tweaked it to reduce it as much as possible using tikz-euclide and symetries. The result is perfect.
Here's the code for those interested :

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
\useasboundingbox (0in,0in) rectangle (6in,6in);
%circle
\def\rad{3in}
\node (O) at (3in,3in) []{};
\draw (O) circle (\rad);
\node (A) at (6in,3in) []{};
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.8pt}
%arcs
\draw (3in,0)--(3in,6in); %vertical
\draw (0,3in)--(6in,3in); %horizontal
\foreach \x/\y in {
2.27947/0.210234,
1.67325/0.431525,
1.22212/0.705443,
0.906042/0.973135,
0.687819/1.20952,
0.53563/1.40973,
0.427272/1.57697,
0.34825/1.71661,
0.289239/1.83382,
0.244185/1.93299,
0.209092/2.01764,
0.181261/2.09053,
0.158834/2.15381,
0.140503/2.20918,
0.125327/2.25798}{
  \tkzClipCircle(O,A)
\pgfmathsetmacro\ny{6-\y}
  \node (z1) at (\x in,\y in) []{};
  \node (z2) at (\x in,\ny in) []{};
  \node (z3) at (\y in,\x in) []{};
  \node (z4) at (\ny in,\x in) []{};
\pgfmathsetmacro\nx{6-\x} 
  \node (z5) at (\y in,\nx in) []{};
  \node (z6) at (\ny in,\nx in) []{};
  \node (z7) at (\nx in,\y in) []{};
  \node (z8) at (\nx in,\ny in) []{};
  \tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=z1 and z2](O,A)
  \tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=z3 and z4](O,A)
  \tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=z5 and z6](O,A)
  \tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=z7 and z8](O,A)
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result :
[image: Poincare's disk]